# What is the function of the 'timestamp' parameter from Sendgrid's Events API post?

Tags: json, api, post, sendgrid

I'm using Sendgrid to log email campaigns and draw statistical analyses from the data. Specifically, I'm talking about Sendgrid's [Events API](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html).

I'm attempting to get the time that the events are happening (process, deliver, open, etc) and I noticed that in the POST that Sendgrid sends, for each event there is 'timestamp' parameter that provides a UNIX style integer timestamp.  An example of some POST data:

```
{"email":"foo@bar.com","timestamp":1322000095,"unique_arg":"my unique arg","event":"delivered"}
```

What exactly is this timestamp referencing?  Is it when the POST was sent by Sendgrid?  Is it when the event occurs?  When it's processed by Sendgrid?  I scoured the web and I still haven't found any specific reference for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just chatted with their support team.  As it turns out, the timestamp is the exact time that the event happens, which is exactly what I was hoping (woot!).